# Integrate JQAssistant-Maven-Plugin with database analysis via RDBMS Plugin

Tags: maven, jqassistant

I´m trying to move my existing software-analysis with jQAssistant (which is basically all steps and scripts in a textfile and executed manually) to the maven-plugin of jQAssistant in order to be able to perform the software-analysis at the build-server.

One step of the analysis is to get information about the database schema. This is done with the RDBMS-Plugin of jQAssistant.

But when i try to perform the analysis with maven the information about the database-connection seems to be lost and no database-analysis is performed at all.

The current code of the plugin-configuration looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant</groupId>
    <artifactId>jqassistant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>cli-default</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>scan</goal>
                <goal>analyze</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Scan -->
                <scanIncludes>
                    <scanInclude>
                        <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@host:1521:sid</url>
                        <scope>rdbms:connection</scope>
                    </scanInclude>
                </scanIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I couldn´t find anything in the documentation. Is this a limitation of the jqassistant-maven-plugin or is this a configuration error?

Comment: Did you try the properties file approach in configuring the connection? (http://jqassistant.github.io/jqassistant/doc/1.8.0/#_rdbms_plugin)
Add a properties file with the name jqassistant.plugin.rdbms-your-identifier.properties onto the scan path.

Comment: The upcomming version 1.9.0 allows you the configure the RDBMS plugin via the POM. There is already a alpba version available with the version 1.9.0-ALPHA1